# Corrupted Drives While Copying Large Files Between LUKS Partitions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, mount, luks

I'm currently in the process of backing up a few terrabytes of files from one drive to another. (both LUKS encrypted HDDs)

Unfortunately, after some time I always end up with `readonly filesystem` errors. Then I'm neither able to unmount the drives nor to cleanly shutdown the computer.

This problem occurs with Fedora as well as Ubuntu. And it occured with each HDD I've tested. Now I have three corrupted HDD's: when mounting I get a `can't read superblock` error. But the LUKS header is still there.

Hence I'm able to mount the drives in readonly mode like this:

```
sudo losetup -o 0x00100000 -r -f /dev/sda
losetup -a | grep sda
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop8 luksrecover
sudo mount -o ro,noload /dev/mapper/luksrecover /media/user/HDD1
```

I've now ran out of hard drives to play with and I'm afraid to losse my data.

Might this be a hardware issue? I can safely say that it is not a problem with the SSD of my Linux. I've exchanged it with another one and the same issues coccured.

Also I've tried copying from the Gnome UI, via `cp` and via `rsync`. All of them resulted in similar issues.

Comment: What filesystems are on the drives, and were they unmounted during the copy?

Comment: Also, what does SMART say for the drives, and have you considered using ddrescue for cloning? ddrescue is deaifned to work at a block level so is likely to be more reliable and better able to manage block devices and disk errors.

Comment: @davidgo I'm using Ext4 with LUKS encryption. And ddrescue isn't really an option, because I have to selectively backup certain files/folders

Comment: Destination drives corrupt, right? If it happens on every drive then it's probably not the drives you're copying to.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen yes right destination drive and sometimes the operatings system, too. Could it be something with RAM or with the motherboard?

Comment: Yes, possibly. Maybe worth running a memory test.

Comment: I'm facing a very similar issue. I'm trying to copy a directory from one drive to another (both ssd, both luks encrypted, second is lvm first isn't), around 50 GB but at some point, around 3GB into the copying process, the source drive (LUKS encrypted) kind of goes to sleep and the operation starts to error out on every file and file manager asks me to "skip" the files or retry, retry never works. I then need to skip ALL the files since the source drive simply stops being accessible and all files are skipped. Sometimes I need to remount for it to become accessible again, sometimes I don't.